# Adding the title for each new Marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My application marked points on the map, I would like to with each new addition of the marker displayed a window of entering the title for the marker.
Nowhere can I find a guide how can I do something like that, somebody have any idea ?
Currenlty i can only make simple title something like this:

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(position)
        .title("something");
```

but it automatically adds each point the same name.

Comment: Please explain little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an edittext alert dialog for input .
In OnMapClickListener onMapClick method open an alert dialog for input.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Marker Title !");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter the title");
        final EditText editText=new EditText(MapsActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(editText);


      alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String name=editText.getText().toString();
                if (name.trim().compareTo("")==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Enter the tile !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else{
     MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title(name);
                }
            }
        });
 alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I need to also add it to the list so I added the line: 'points.add(x, xMarker =xMap.addMarker(options));' ---> in else,  but when I wanted to use this list again, it's also the names from editText will be in this list ? or i need something more ?

Answer (score 0):

Use specific `LatLng` to plot title of that marker, give title to every new `Latlng`:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(your_latLng_for_everyMarker)
            .draggable(false)
            .title("something"));
```

Comment: but I would like that when you add a new marker, the application displayed a window with edittext and download the title from the user

Comment: Are u doing this on runtime ? Did u have more code to post ?

Comment: i want to start coding, but don't know what i should do on the start

Comment: So, make a database to store `LatLng` and `title`. In app allow the user to add marker by placing a button(just saying) when user clicks(for this u will need google map tutorials to convert the address to latlng on map), once clicked prompt a window to add address and tilte once done save it to server.